# If a subsequence of $(a_n)$ converges to a limit $L$, prove that $(a_n)$, which is non-decreasing, also converges to $L$

Tags: real-analysis

I know that if a sequence converges to $L$, its subsequences also converge to $L$. However, I'm not sure how to show the converse in this case, given $a_n$ is monotonic.

If I show somehow that $a_n$ is bounded, can I say that by the monotone convergence theorem $a_n$ converges to L because its subsequence does? If so, how would I begin in proving $a_n$ is bounded? Thanks for any advice

Comment: A monotone sequence (your original sequence $(a_n)$) has a unique limit in $[-\infty,\infty]$. Any subsequence must have the same limit. So, *all* subsequences have this common limit. And, given this limit of any subsequence, it is necessarily the limit of the sequence.

Comment: Let the subsequence be $(a_{n_k})$. Given $\epsilon\gt 0$, there is a $W$ such that if $k\gt W$, then $L-\epsilon\lt a_{n_k}\le L$. By monotonicity, if $n\gt n_W$, then $L-\epsilon\lt a_n\le L$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas how do you prove that if $a_{n_k}<\epsilon+l\Rightarrow a_{n_k}\le l$, with $l\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The proof I sketched in the above comment does not use that,  thatès a separate question, versions of which hhave been answered several times on MSE. (We must assume that the inequality holds for all positive $àepsilon$.)  Unfortunately, MSE is hard to search, so I cannot give you a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can proved by contradiction.  Suppose $(a_{n})$ is a real, non-decreasing sequence which has a subsequence converging to limit $L$.  We want to prove $a_{n}$ converges to $L$.

Suppose by contradiction that $a_{n}$ does not converge to $L$.  That means $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $\forall N \in \Bbb N$, $\exists m \geq N$ with $a_{m} \not \in (L - \epsilon, L + \epsilon)$.  Denote the subsequence that converges to $L$ by $(a_{n_{k}})$.  We know since $a_{n_{k}} \to L$, there is $K \in \Bbb N$ such that $k \geq K$ implies $a_{n_{k}} \in (L - \epsilon, L + \epsilon)$.

Since the sequence in non-decreasing, and $a_{n_{k}} \in (L - \epsilon, L + \epsilon)$, and $(a_{n})$ doesn't converge to $L$ by assumption, then there is some $m'$ such that $a_{m'} \geq L + \epsilon$.  But we have $\forall k \geq K$, $a_{n_{k}} \in (L - \epsilon, L + \epsilon)$, and for some $k$, $n_{k} > m'$ )(which implies $a_{m'} \leq a_{n_{k}}$ since $(a_{n})$ is non-decreasing).  But then $a_{n_{k}} < L + \epsilon \leq a_{m'}$, which implies $a_{n_{k}} < a_{m'}$ even though $m' < n_{k}$, which contradicts the fact that the sequence is non-decreasing.

So, the sequence $(a_{n})$ must converge to $L$.